# Selenium can't found valid item from iframe

Tags: python, selenium, captcha, hcaptcha

I have code:

```
self.driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementsByName("h-captcha-response")[0].setAttribute("h-captcha-response", "{token}")')
self.driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementsByName("g-recaptcha-response")[0].setAttribute("g-recaptcha-response", "{token}")')
self.driver.find_element_by_id('checkbox').click()
time.sleep(5)
```

and that code don't click at the item with id checkbox (check [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrpMJ.png))

i think the iframe upper makes big problems (check [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h88oz.png))

if this is right version of solving problem, how to refocus Selenium onto that iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that `driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);` would work but

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name,'a-')]")));
```

might.